# Node JS & pdfkit - addPage() loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node.js and [pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org/index.html) to generate name tag labels. The goal is to send an array of people objects with First & Last names and the Quantity `qty` of labels for each person. Here's what I've come up with:

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

var people = [
    {qty:2, first:'Bob', last:'Hope'},
    {qty:3, first:'Bing', last:'Crosby'}
];

function makePDF (people) {

    var doc = new PDFDocument({
        size: [165,288],
        margins: 1
    }),
    firstTag = true;

    doc.rotate(90);

    // Loop through each person
    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {

        // Generate each name tag
        for (var x = 0; x < people[i].qty; x++) {

            if (firstTag) {// First page is automatically created
                firstTag = false;
            } else {// The rest must be added
                doc.addPage();
            }

            doc.fontSize(40).text(people[i].first, 13, -150);
            doc.fontSize(16).text(people[i].last, 15, -117);

        }
    }

    doc.write('tags.pdf');
}

makePDF(people);
```

This generates a 5-page pdf (it should have 2 of one person and 3 of the other) - but only the first tag has information on it, the rest are blank.

How do I correctly use `addPage()` in this scenario? Or is there a better way to get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - evidently every time I add a new page I have to rotate it.

`doc.addPage()` on Line 16 becomes `doc.addPage().rotate(90)`

Comment: .: Are you sure that this worked? I get the error
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Server.<anonymous> (g:\test\test.js:19:16)
    at Server.emit (events.js:110:17)
    .....`